# List of thermodynamic processes

Tags: thermodynamics

Can anyone give me a list of all the possible types of thermodynamic processes ?

Like we can have : reverse adiabatic expansion, irreversible isobar contraction etc etc. The combinations are limitless and I don't understand the basis of classification.

Thanks

Comment: *give me a list of all the possible types* … *the combinations are limitless* Those two things are incompatible.

Comment: It is not a "classification" as such. There are an infinite number of possible thermodynamic processes. The ones we give names to are just special cases with nice properties

Comment: I see. I am confused because we have combinations all the time. But thx !

Comment: I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_process) could help you a lot. (Really?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) We can start by writing the [fundamental relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_thermodynamic_relation) for the system of interest and considering keeping any variable constant. For example, for a system that we can heat, do work on (compression, electrical, and surface work, say), and add mass to, then the fundamental relation is

$$dU=T\,dS-P\,dV+E\,dD+\sigma\,dA+\mu\,dN,$$

where $U$ is energy, $T$ is temperature, $S$ is entropy, $P$ is pressure, $V$ is volume, $E$ is electric field, $D$ is polarization, $\sigma$ is surface tension, $A$ is surface area, $\mu$ is the chemical potential, and $N$ is the amount of material.

Note that each pair is a [thermodynamic conjugate pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_variables_(thermodynamics)). The sole negative sign arises because pressure is a negative equitriaxial stress that tends to reduce the volume.

Now it's just a matter of remembering the terms: isenergic (constant energy $U$), isothermal (constant temperature $T$), isentropic (constant entropy $S$), closed (constant mass $N$), equilibrium with another phase (equal chemical potentials $\mu$) and so on. So we have 11 simple conditions we might apply during a process on this particular idealized system of interest.

(2) It can also be useful to classify a process as irreversible (entropy producing) or reversible (entropy conserving). All real processes are irreversible, but we can often come arbitrarily close to reversibility, an idealization, by reducing friction, gradients, turbulence, etc.

(3) There are a limitless number of other conditions we might maintain. For example, we might manually process a thin film under the condition of constant color, which might depend on the thickness, stress, impurity concentration and temperature.

(4) Finally, there's the name of the process, which usually emphasizes the aspect that's important to us: an expansion, for example, which increases the volume $V$ and generally provides us with useful work. Or heating, or mixing, or pressurization.

Putting these together, we might speak of, for example, *reversible polarization* at *constant volume* and *constant electric field* (i.e., $D$ is increasing while $S$, $V$, and $E$ remain constant).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the familiar reversible thermodynamic processes involving ideal gases are special cases of the general reversible polytropic process, which is generally written as

$$pV^{n}=C$$

where $n$ is called the polytropic index (not to be confused with $n$ being the number of moles of a gas) and $C$ is a constant. The equation can be used to describe various different expansion and compression processes depending on the value of the polytropic index. Examples are

$n=0$ for an isobaric (constant pressure) process

$n=$ + infinity for an isochoric (constant volume) process

$n=1$ for an ideal gas isothermal (constant temperature) process

$n=\gamma = \frac{C_P}{C_V}$ for an ideal gas isentropic (reversible adiabatic) process

Theoretically, since there are an infinite number of possible values of n, there are an infinite number of possible processes capable of connecting two equilibrium states, not just the ones listed above, as long as the laws of thermodynamics are not violated.

Finally, for an ideal gas, closed system (no change in mass), the ideal gas equation
$$pV=nRT$$

Where $n$ is the number of moles of gas, and $R$ the universal gas constant, can be applied at each stage of a reversible process.
.

Hope this helps.